# Github network graph doesn't show branch

Tags: git, github

Why is the yellow-branch not jutting out and then back in on the second to last commit?

I made a branch via the git command line and took the following steps:

1. Made new branch
2. Added feature
3. Committed a few times and pushed
4. `git checkout master`
5. `git merge yellow-branch`
6. `git push`
7. `git branch -d yellow-branch`

While I was working on the yellow-branch, the network graph was correctly displaying a separate line beneath the master branch for yellow-branch. Was it because I used the cli and not the point and click method on the github website?

[image: yellow branch]

**EDIT**

I was looking at another repo that has the branches jutting out (below). The master branch has at least one commit to that is made while the other branch is not yet merged. Maybe this branch jutting out only occurs while one branch is not even with its parent branch?

[image: multiple branches]

Comment: I doubt that it's because you used the CLI rather than the website. Anyway, are the commit logs identical or is there an additional commit on the master branch that isn't in the yellow-branch...If you didn't delete the remote yellow-branch already that is.

Comment: @dimwittedanimal There is an additional commit on the master branch that isn't on the yellow-branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior because both branches have the exact same commit history. The branches would remain separate in the network graph representation if they had a [divergent history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#divergent_history).